# Prevent cmd from breaking line read on space delimiter

Tags: apache, batch-file, batch-processing

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (httpd.conf) do (
echo %%a
)
```

I have a file that looks like this:

```
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"
Listen 80
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
```

however when i run the batch file, it outputs this:

```
ServerRoot
Listen
LoadModule
LoadModule
```

it appears that cmd is only fetching the line UP TO the first space character... Does anybody know how to get the whole line?

**I've tried adding options to the for command... these have been tried and these all fail:**

```
for /f "eol=# tokens=1-9 delims=¬"
for /f "tokens=* delims=¬"
for /f "tokens=* delims=:\="
for /f "tokens=1-6"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "delims=" to your command in order for it to process lines which include spaces in them. So, your code should look a bit like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (httpd.conf) do (
echo %%a
)
```

Also you can add more delimiters to your list like commas, etc. To do that you just add the characters to the "delims =,+"

Comment: I have. I used a for command just like this to copy files that include spaces in their names.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I added an extra space in there. Take out the space in the delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't try the below option, I bet. Note that there is no space after `=`.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (httpd.conf) do (
    echo %%a
)
```